# Comparing two time-series in a panel dataset

Tags: time-series, self-study, panel-data

I have a panel dataset ($N>3000$, $t>200$) containing two variables for stock prices:  one comes from the market and the other from simulation.  I want to see what is the relation between other factors, such as size and benchmark (*B/M*), and the wedge between the simulated price and the real price. So, real price and simulated price are the dependent variables and some other factors like size and B/M are independent variable.

1. Assuming that we face autocorrelation in the data, can I still use panel models?
2. I'm not familiar with multivariate time series models (VAR, VECM, ...). If I need to use these models could you please point me out to a reasonable model that I can start with?
3. I also heard about panel time series models. What is the difference between these models and multivariate time-series models?